# Запрет на просмотр страницы

Tags: php, ajax

Как запретить просматривать директорию, чтобы в нее не могли попасть через url. Но! Если обращаться через AJAX то все работало?

Например. Если в адресной строке такой url: example.com/system/s/main.php, то содержимое сей директории скрыть, а если обращаться через ajax по тому же url, содержимое показать.

Comment: Следует понимать, что защитой данное поведение не является.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно проверить тип запроса. И пропускать только ajax-запросы. На низком уровне это сможно сделать так:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
        && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
        && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // это AJAX
} else {
    // это НЕ AJAX
}
```

В большинстве современных фреймворков есть специальные классы/методы для проверки таких запросов. Обычно они называются как-нибудь `isXmlHttpRequest()`.

Так же Вы, возможно, захотите, чтобы этот запрос можно было отправлять только с Вашего сайта. Тогда Вам нужно ввести дополнительную проверку на хост-отправитель. Обычно достаточно проверить переменную `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`: она должна содержать значение, равное доменному имени Вашего сайта.

Comment: В последнем абзаце: проверять надо скорее referrer, но от направленных на сервис атак и это не поможет.

Comment: В последнем абзаце написан ад.